# how to combine rescue multiple exceptions in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

is it possible to combine multiple rescue statements into one in ruby on rails.

```
begin
   //do something 
  rescue ArgumentError => e
      e.message
  rescue NameError => e
      e.message
  rescue StandardError => e
      e.message
end
```

combined to something like below

```
rescue ArgumentError, NameError, StandardError => e
      e.message
```

Comment: Yes, it's done exactly like your supposition `rescue ArgumentError, NameError, StandardError => e`. Did you try running that and have issues of some kind that you meant to ask about?

Comment: @SimpleLime - i tried it, but wasn't sure, if order of the exceptions would matter here.

Comment: Order matters when you have multiple rescue blocks (your first code block) because as soon as you match you execute that block and are done so you want more specific subclasses above the more general parent classes. When moving them to a single line (one rescue block) order doesn't matter: only one exception can be raised and they all will funnel into that block if they match)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will work. You'll want to consider how and whether you expect this code to change in the future, and whether this format is conducive to that change.

This is also a good candidate for writing the code and seeing what happens (especially if you can reproduce the appropriate behavior with a test), even if only in the rails console. You might find a faster feedback loop there.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to add separate exceptions for those. Because **ArgumentError** and **NameError** are under **StandardError**.

Here is the exceptions hierarchy.

```
- NoMemoryError
- ScriptError
    - LoadError
    - NotImplementedError
    - SyntaxError
- SecurityError
- SignalException
    - Interrupt
- StandardError (default for `rescue`)
    - ArgumentError
        - UncaughtThrowError
    - EncodingError
    - FiberError
    - IOError
        - EOFError
    - IndexError
        - KeyError
        - StopIteration
    - LocalJumpError
    - NameError
        - NoMethodError
    - RangeError
        - FloatDomainError
    - RegexpError
    - RuntimeError (default for `raise`)
    - SystemCallError
        - Errno::*
    - ThreadError
    - TypeError
    - ZeroDivisionError
- SystemExit
- SystemStackError
- fatal (impossible to rescue)
```